# What is the Status of Borel conjecture today?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-group-theory, manifolds, conjectures

Let me recall the conjecture: $M$ and $N$ two aspherical closed $n$-manifolds with isomorphic fundamental groups, then $M$ and $N$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: See the manifold atlas [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Aspherical_manifolds#The_Borel_Conjecture) for a summary of what I think are fairly up to date results.

Comment: This is a question better answered by 5 minutes in front of a Google prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Surely the state of the art is in this paper from a few days ago at http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00262 by some of the leading experts in the field.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the abstract/introduction. But, it seems to me that they have proved the conjecture as they state it as questions of Borel.  Is this correct?!

Comment: They proved a brilliant result but it's not the same conjecture :-)